# Counting total likes a facebook user has received

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Is it possible with the iOS FB API to tell how many 'likes' a facebook user has received over a given time? I want to be able to display to the user how many likes they have received in a given day/week/month etc.

Cheers,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using FQL, it appears to be possible, but since "likes" don't apply to users, but to the objects that users create, it appears that you'll have to first query for a user's objects (status updates, photos, links, videos, etc.) and then determine the number of likes per object:

```
SELECT object_id, object_type, post_id, user_id FROM like WHERE object_id = XXX
```

If you are looking for the number of likes a user has given, the FQL is:

```
SELECT object_id, object_type, post_id FROM like WHERE user_id = <userid>
```

The documentation for querying likes is here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like

You can play around with the Graph API and issue sample FQL queries here: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Integrating FQL queries with the FB iOS SDK is discussed here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/run-fql-queries-ios-sdk/